# How to "Dequeue" Element from a List?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a `List` of cards called _deck:

```
 private List<String> _deck = new List<String> {"2h", "3h", "4h", ... }
```

And then I want to remove a card from the `List` and save into a variable. I'm trying to do:

```
 String p1FirstCard = _deck.RemoveAt(0);
```

but I'm getting the error

> Cannot convert type void to String

In C# `List` is there something like push/pop but which does that at the "head" or "start" of the `List`?  (Push/pop works at the "tail" or "end" of the list.)

If not, how should I do remove the first element but save it in a variable?

Comment: why don't you use  Queue<T> instead ?

Comment: looks like your list of cards is called '_deck'

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

```
String p1FirstCard = _deck[0];
_deck.RemoveAt(0);
```

You can write your own extension helper method (I added an index to `Pop`, as @Fredou suggested:

```
static class ListExtension
{
    public static T PopAt<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
    {
        T r = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        return r;
    }
}
```

and then call

```
String p1FirstCard = _deck.PopAt(0);
```

P.S. **The name can be a bit confusing.** `Pop` usually removes the last element, not the first one.

Comment: maybe you should change your code to use a parameter to return/remove an item by index, that would give all possible choice to the OP

Comment: Nice. For a shuffled deck it really doesn't matter whether I pull from the top or bottom of the deck so this is awesome. thanks.

Comment: you can also add `index = 0` in the _method declaration_ to remove first element as an **default action**  and avoid passing the `index` parameter. I think is useful because you want, generally, remove the first element.

Answer (score 69):

If you want to dequeue the first element, you  could simply use a [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _deck = new Queue<String>();
        _deck.Enqueue("2h");
        _deck.Enqueue("3h");
        _deck.Enqueue("4h");
        _deck.Enqueue("...");

        var first = _deck.Dequeue(); // 2h
        first = _deck.Dequeue(); // 3h
    }
}
```

If you want to pop the last element, you could use a [`Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _deck = new Stack<String>();
        _deck.Push("2h");
        _deck.Push("3h");
        _deck.Push("4h");
        _deck.Push("...");

        var first = _deck.Pop(); // ...
        first = _deck.Pop(); // 4h
    }
}
```

Comment: You meant a generic version perhaps: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Comment: Neither the C# Stack or Queue will remove from the *end* of the list, which is how actionscript's [`pop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#pop%28%29) works.  Doesn't mean they're not the correct choices, just that neither one is a perfect match.

Comment: @Bobson, i did read the question again to make sure i wasn't wrong but where does he ask for the last one being removed? the code is showing the first element only being removed

Comment: @Fredou - The OP doesn't, but since he references `pop()`, I assumed that was the behavior he expected.

Comment: @Bobson, the question is confusing but i think i agree with you

Comment: Pop and Dequeue do remove from the end of the list. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.pop(v=vs.110).aspx or here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Building on [AlexD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24855920/4298200), I added a couple more extension methods:

```
public static class ListExtensionMethods
{
    public static T PopAt<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
    {
        var r = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        return r;
    }

    public static T PopFirst<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        var index = list.FindIndex(predicate);
        var r = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        return r;
    }

    public static T PopFirstOrDefault<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) where T : class
    {
        var index = list.FindIndex(predicate);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            var r = list[index];
            list.RemoveAt(index);
            return r;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a direct equivalent to `pop()`, you'll have to write your own, because I don't think a `List` has a "Remove from end and return".  However, there are both the [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (first in, first out) and the [`Stack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (first in, last out) classes instead of just a `List`.

There's also the [`LinkedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which lets you add to or remove from both the beginning or the end, but the provided `RemoveFirst()` and `RemoveLast()` methods don't automatically return the item being removed - you'd need to write an extension method like AlexD's to do that.

All of these deal with removing things from the beginning or the end of the list.  If you just want to remove an arbitrary item from the middle of a `List`, there's always `List.Remove(item)` which removes a specific item from the list (rather than by position).

Answer (score 2):

```
 private List<String> _deck = new List<String> {"2h", "3h", "4h", ... }
 //Save into variable first
 String p1FirstCard = _deck[0];
 //Now just remove it
 _deck.RemoveAt(0);
```

`RemoveAt(int)` doesn't return anything.